# Conditional removal of columns in sparse matrix

Tags: python, performance, matrix, numpy, scipy

I have a large dataset (78k instances x 490k features) that is loaded as a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` format. From this dataset I want to filter certain features (i.e. columns) for which all values fall below a certain threshold.

Loading the dataset as a dense matrix is not an option, nor did I find sparse matrix operation that do the job (please correct me if I am wrong on the latter). So I took a column-iteration approach for each feature group using `multiprocessing`:

1. Divide the total column indices in `n = n_cores` roughly equal groups.
2. For every index group spawn a process that iterates over each column and use buildin `.all()` to check the comparison condition. Collect all indices that should be deleted in list (order does not matter).
3. Drop the columns in the full dataset matrix `X` based on the indices list.

On a 48-core@2.50GHz machine this takes 42 minutes on my dataset. I feel that especially the .all() conditional check in `.get_filtered_cols` should be optimized. Any other recommendations are certainly welcome.

Code with smaller simulated dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import multiprocessing

# Initiate simulated random sparse csr matrix as dataset X. Actual use case is 78k x 490k.
N = 780; M = 4900
X = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], size=(N,M), p=[0.99, 0.005, 0.0025, 0.0015, 0.001]) # this is a rough
# simulation of the type of data in the use case (of course upperbound of some features is much higher)
X = csr_matrix(X, dtype=np.float32) # the real-use svmlight dataset can only be loaded as sparse.csr_matrix

# The settings of the feature groups to be filtered. Contains the range of the feature group in the dataset and the
# threshold value.
ngram_fg_dict = {"featuregroup_01": {"threshold": 3, "start_idx": 0, "end_idx": 2450},
                 "featuregroup_02": {"threshold": 4, "start_idx": 2451, "end_idx": 4900}}
n_cores = 3

def list_split(lst, n):
    '''Split a list into roughly equal n groups'''
    k, m = int(len(lst) / n), int(len(lst) % n)
    return [lst[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in list(range(n))]

def get_filtered_cols(indices):
    '''Takes a list of column indices of the dataset to check if all column values are smaller than k'''
    col_idc_delete = []
    for i in indices:
        col = fg_X[:,i].toarray().flatten()
        if all(i < v["threshold"] for i in col):
            col_idc_delete.append(i+v["start_idx"]) #these are the indices for the original dataset (not yet sliced)
    return col_idc_delete

def drop_cols(M, idx_to_drop):
    '''Remove columns from matrix M given a list of column indices to remove.'''
    idx_to_drop = np.unique(idx_to_drop)
    C = M.tocoo()
    keep = ~np.in1d(C.col, idx_to_drop)
    C.data, C.row, C.col = C.data[keep], C.row[keep], C.col[keep]
    C.col -= idx_to_drop.searchsorted(C.col)    # decrement column indices
    C._shape = (C.shape[0], C.shape[1] - len(idx_to_drop))
    return C.tocsr()

all_idc_delete = []

for k, v in ngram_fg_dict.items():
    if v["threshold"] > 1: # '1' in threshold_dict means 'set no threshold' given our dataset
        fg_X = X[:,v["start_idx"]:v["end_idx"]] # slice feature group to be filtered
        l = fg_X.shape[1] # total amount of columns
        # split the feature column indices list in groups for multiprocessing, the conditional check is to remove
        # potential empty lists  resulting from list_split
        mp_groups = [lgroup for lgroup in list_split(list(range(l)), n_cores) if lgroup != []]
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(len(mp_groups))
        print("Filtering %s < %d with %d processes" % (k, v["threshold"], len(mp_groups)))
        fg_idc_delete = p.imap(get_filtered_cols, mp_groups) #imap faster than map, order of returned result column
        # indices does not matter
        all_idc_delete.extend([item for sublist in fg_idc_delete for item in sublist]) #flatten before extending to
        # all indices to delete list

print("Deleting %s columns." % (len(all_idc_delete)))
X_new = drop_cols(X, all_idc_delete)
```

Benchmarking this 30x: time avg: 2.67 sec, best: 2.41 sec. on my local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the threshold is positive, then you can use the `>=` operator to construct a sparse Boolean array indicating which points are above or equal to the threshold:

```
# m is your dataset in sparse matrix representation
above_threshold = m >= v["threshold"]
```

and then you can use the `max` method to get the maximum entry in each column:

```
cols = above_threshold.max(axis=0)
```

This will be 1 for columns that have any value greater than or equal to the threshold, and 0 for columns where all values are below the threshold. So `cols` is a mask for the columns you want to keep. (If you need a Boolean array, then use `cols == 1`.)

(*Updated after discussion in comments. I had some more complicated suggestions, but simpler is better.*)

Comment: Thanks. The speed advantage of converting to csc is marginal though as we only have to slice along the column for each feature group (max 4). I benchmarked with csc and average time improvement is 3.2%, best time improvement is 8.5%.

Comment: @GJacobs: did you re-implement the column filtering operation to take advantage of the CSC format?

Comment: No, because -to my knowledge- there is no way to perform a boolean mask or `.all()`-like function directly on a sparse matrix. So I end up iterating over columns in the exact same way as currently implemented. A way to perform the conditional check in `.all()` efficiently without iterating over every column (either over the full matrix or in batches) would solve this problem.

Comment: @GJacobs: see updated post.

Comment: Thank you! You really saved my bacon here! I will update OP with full working code for future reference.

Comment: Don't. If you want you can put it as an answer, but do not put it in the original, as it will make it very hard to understand what happened.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/a/38945428/901925 I suggested `above_threshold.sum(axis=0)`.  I wonder which is faster.  But the column delete (or select in my answer) probably takes a lot more time.